# How to send new update notifications to users' devices

Tags: android

If my new apk version is in drop box then How to send new update notifications to users' devices.

Is it possible?

Note:my apk is not available in google play

Comment: You have to do it yourself with something like GCM for example

Comment: Another idea might be using a platform like HockeyApp which handles the (beta) app distribution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use some kind of push notification platform like google`s firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/
Using firebase you can send push notifications from their console or your own webservices and in each push notification you can enter any data you want the user to use, for example a link to the .apk you want him to download.
And then the user can install it like here: 
[Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

It is called **push notifications.** You can learn it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_push_notification.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You need API which sends you apk version detail and then compare/check your current running application versio, if it is lower then show notification to user for app update or download new apk and install programmatically.